# Catching error when OpenLayers map disappears

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers.

After spend some time on another page and turn back to map page i can't see the map. I see only gray background. There isn't any console error. If i resize the window map is appearing again.
I don't know how to catch the error with it's real reason on the console side.

Could you suggest to me any error handling method to catch the error with it's reason?

Comment: If you control or can detect when you return to the map page try calling `map.updateSize()` or `map.render()` to force a refresh.  It could also be a browser or device issue, e.g. if you are using WebGL layers the GL context could be lost.

Comment: We tried map.UpdateSize but we are calling map for every 10 seconds so map is disappearing still for 1o seconds than it appears. We are not using WebGL.